# Weak derivative of generalized stepfunction?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be a function that is equal to $x$ for $t<0$ and $y$ for $t\ge0$. Can we write down the weak derivative of this function at $t=0$?

Comment: The weak derivative is $(y-x) \delta(t)$, assuming $x,y$ are fixed.

Comment: thank you, feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weak derivative is $(y-x) \delta(t)$, assuming $x,y$ are fixed.